# How to use `<count>` and `-count` to make command repeatable?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to use `<count>` and `-count` to make a command repeatable. This is the command I have right now:

```
command! -count=1 Hello :d <count>.
```

But I got this error instead when I run `:Hello`:

```
E488: Trailing characters: :d 1.
```

How can I get its syntax correctly?

Comment: Is the issue the trailing `.` you have in the command definition?

Comment: yes, just remove the trailing `.` and it should just work

Comment: But how can I make this `:d` repeat? How can a command take [count]?

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? What do you mean with `repeat`?